# Excel vba - how to find digit no 8 in cell and evaluate if it's the correct one

Tags: excel, vba

Got this vba so far:

```
For Each cell In Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
If Len(cell.Value) = 11 Then
cell.Copy Destination:=Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End If
Next cell
```

I need to add some code behind "11" in the second line, but I can't figure out how to write it. What I want to do is to add something like "`and digit number 8 (of 11) is 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9 then`".
Anyone that can help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
For Each cell In Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Len(cell.Value) = 11 Then
        Select Case Mid(cell.Value, 8, 1)
        Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
             cell.Copy Destination:=Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End Select
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Now, that's the one I was looking for! Thanks a lot for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't follow your explanation but according to your title, you need to check if the 8th character is a string (from a cell, etc) is "the right one":

```
Function Check8thCharacter(myString As String, theRightOne As String) As Boolean
    Check8thCharacter = (Mid(myString, 8, 1) = theRightOne)
End Function
```

Here's an example of it in use:

```
Sub Digit8()
    Range("A1") = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM"
    Const testRightOne = "H"
    If Check8thCharacter(Range("A1"), testRightOne) Then
        MsgBox "It's the right one!"
    Else
        MsgBox "It's the wrong one."
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Another look at your question makes me wonder if you're actually trying to determine whether the eighth character of a cell is an ***odd number***, which is only a slight variation:

```
Function Is8thOdd(rg As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next 'error will also return false
    Is8thOdd = (Mid(rg, 8, 1) / 2 <> Mid(rg, 8, 1) \ 2)
End Function
```

Here's an example of it in use:

```
Sub Digit8()
    If Is8thOdd(Range("A1")) Then
        MsgBox "Yes, it's odd"
    Else
        MsgBox "No, it's not odd."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I can be misunderstood. English is not my native language... :-) All cells in column A holds numbers, and I want to copy from A to B those cells that holds exactly 11 characters, but only when character number 8 (counting from left) is "1" or "3" or "5" or "7" or "9".

Comment: You don't really need the `Is8thOdd` function. `If Mid(Range("A1"), 8, 1) Mod 2 Then` will do it. Just have to deal with `type mismatch` if there isn't a number at position 8.